# Sort a Java TreeSet using Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, set, comparator, treeset

i am trying to sort a `TreeSet` of objects ("Etudiant") using `Comparator` interface . This the `Comparator` implementation:

```
import java.util.Comparator;


public class TriParNom implements Comparator<Etudiant>{
    public int compare(Etudiant o1, Etudiant o2) {
        return o1.getNom().compareTo(o2.getNom());
    }
}
```

here is the the TreeSet declaration and the call of the comparator in the main :

```
TreeSet<Etudiant> University= new TreeSet<Etudiant>(new TriParNom());
```

the error i get in the main class when i declare the TreeSet and call the comparator ,is : no suitable constructor found for TreeSet(TriParNom) .

Any solutions please ? thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you add your import statements to the question. I assume that you are using a different TreeSet or Comparator.

Comment: import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

Comment: and the imports for `TriParNom` ?

Comment: @k5 TriParNom is a class in the same package so no need for import !

Comment: It needs to import java.util.Comparator. If it doesn't, you have your answer: you created your own Comparator interface. Don't do that.

Comment: The class `TriParNom` needs to import `java.util.Comparator`. If it doesnt, that means there is a different `Comparator` class in that package.

Comment: I add the import from the OP comment, maybe they are not the import of TriParNom class, @YassinGharsallah please edit your post and put the correct import for TriParNom, and also the import for classe where the main is

Comment: there is no errors in TriParNom class and the comparator is already imported

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. We must be able to copy the code you post, paste it without any modification in our IDE, and see the problem reproduce.

Comment: @JBNizet the code is already in the post you have just to create a class named à 'Etudiant' then the comparator class and a main class to declare the treeSet ( all the code is there )

Comment: What's unclear in "We must be able to copy the code you post, paste it without any modification in our IDE, and see the problem reproduce."? All the code isn't there at all. Just read your question.

Comment: Given that the error message mentions TreeSet, and not jaa.util.TreeSet, my guess is that your classes are in the default package, and that you have defined your own TreeSet class. But you didn't post a complete minimal example, so that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a very simple implementation based on the information you provided, and I give you my results:

[image: project structure]

The Etudiant class is a very simple pojo

```
public class Etudiant {

private String nom;

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}   }
```

The TriParNom class is the plain Comparator you described:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class TriParNom implements Comparator<Etudiant> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Etudiant o1, Etudiant o2) {
        return o1.getNom().compareTo(o2.getNom());
    }

}
```

And here is a simple class with an entry point and a sample method to exercise the newly created treeset

```
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Etudiant> u = new TreeSet<>(new TriParNom());
        System.out.printf("size? %d%n", u.size());      
    }

}
```

Execution results follow:

[image: exec]

Apparently, there are no compilation errors either.

Answer (score 1):

If your code matches to the snippet given below, then it should run fine without problems. The moment you remove the part `implements Comparator<Etudiant>` from `class TriParNom`, you will get the error indicating suitable constructor not found. Now, one another silly way it could happen if you haven't recompiled your classes after you implemented the comparator to your `TriParNom` - but that's too obvious. Have your class that contins `main` method(that declares Treeset) imported `java.util.TreeSet` ?

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class TreesetCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Etudiant> University= new TreeSet<Etudiant>(new TriParNom());
    }
}

class TriParNom implements Comparator<Etudiant>{
    public int compare(Etudiant o1, Etudiant o2) {
        return o1.getNom().compareTo(o2.getNom());
    }
}

class Etudiant {
    public String getNom() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "some";
    }
}
```

Comment: the error i got is when  i declare the treeset in the main and i give it the comparator in parameter ! there are no other errors in the other classes

Comment: do u use an IDE to compile & run it ?

Comment: either you haven't implemented comparator to `TriParNom`, or it is not re-compiled(manually or by IDE) after you implemented the comparator. Because the error what you got shows up when the class does not have a comparator `javac com/TreesetCheck.java` 
`com/TreesetCheck.java:8: error: no suitable constructor found for TreeSet(TriParNom)`